# incorrectly floating elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a bunch of anchor tags containing images and a h1 header. I have apllied the float element to allow them to layout in rows of 2. For some strange reason though, the milky way link is causing the next anchor to float right. If you swap the milky way with saturn, it works fine. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Can anyone explain this strange phenomenon to me?

Here's the jsfiddle for my page: http://jsfiddle.net/SVuQQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `clear:both` to the Andromeda anchor it will fix the float issue. I [set it up](http://jsfiddle.net/SVuQQ/3/) so you can just add the `.clear` class to any other anchors that might need it if you add more.

Explanation: An element with `clear:both` prevents elements to the left and right with floats from having an effect on the flow of the page layout. In this case, the milky way anchor float was having an adverse effect on the elements below. By adding `clear:both` to the Andromeda anchor, the Milky Way's float is no longer pushing down the rest of the elements.

Alternative Solution: The float issue is happening because you have anchor tags with different heights. They can't stack properly because one float is pushing down farther than the other. If you set the same height for all of them it would fix the issue without clear:both. [jsfiddle.net/SVuQQ/7](http://jsfiddle.net/SVuQQ/7/)

Comment: this solution fixed it. however, i'll only +1 with a better explanation on WHY it works rather than "it just does".

Comment: Explanation added, hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: ok, but WHY was it having an effect on the flow of the page layout. THAT's what i'm asking an explanation for. yeah i know that the clear fixes it, but what exactly is it fixing? is that clear? (pun intended)

Comment: The float issue is happening because you have anchor tags with different heights. They can't stack properly because one float is pushing down farther than the other. If you set the same height for all of them it would fix the issue without `clear:both`. http://jsfiddle.net/SVuQQ/7/

Comment: now THAT'S what i was looking for. thank you. also, you might want to put that into the answer. you might get more +1's

Answer (score -1):

I suggest try to set your #subject-content a-menu {height: auto}

and remove float:left at the same line (e.g #subject-content a-menu)

Comment: downvoted for the same reason as Kumar's answer. I clearly state in my question that I have the `float: left` there for a reason.

Comment: When I type my answer I didn't know that someone answer it already! My bad!